# How to get data in Retrofit from nested JSON array using view binding android

Tags: android, arrays, json, nested, retrofit

Hi Every one will you please help me to fatch data from nested JSON array in recycler view  using retrofit from starting to end thankyou

Comment: in step (03) Interface(Api) - KidsGameApiCall  -  You need to add sub image url

Comment: Dont Forget to // Take internet Permission in manifests
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
See Overview Of All activity or class or interfaces whichever we need to make & same we will make it below 

Here we hide some API data for security purpose & u can remove some Common class data as we set static sound method in it so

we have to set as a Main Image Item or Sub Image Item as per API
API -> https://________.in/childrenart/kidsgames.json

Here We have JSON Format like below - Nested Array

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "profile_image": "https://________.in/childrenart/profileimages/kg_maze_games.png",
    "category_name": "kg_maze_games",
    "category_images": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "image_url": "https://________.in/childrenart/category_images/kg_maze_games/kg_maze_games_01.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "image_url": "https://________.in/childrenart/category_images/kg_maze_games/kg_maze_games_02.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "profile_image": "https://________.in/childrenart/profileimages/kg_match_count.png",
    "category_name": "kg_match_count",
    "category_images": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "image_url": "https://________.in/childrenart/category_images/kg_match_count/kg_match_count_01.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "image_url": "https://________.in/childrenart/category_images/kg_match_count/kg_match_count_02.png"
      }
    ]
  }
]

https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
Convert this JSON to POJO You will get 2 Ready Model Class
Dont forget to Set Source type: as a JSON & Annotation style: Gson in the below link
Paste your JSON Data & Get model class as a Zip or copy from Preview
https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Now Create new Project in java & Add below Depndencies

in -> build.gradle(Module)

// gson Retrofit
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.1'
// glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.0'

in -> Gradle.properties

android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Now Lest start to make classes , interfaces , activities as below 14 step wise

To Get Main Iamge From API (profile_image)

Step Type                       -              Name

(01) Model Class                -              Main Image Item
(02) Model Class                -              Sub Image Item
(03) Interface(Api)             -              KidsGameApiCall
(04) Activity(Main)             -              KidsGameActivity
(05) Activity(MainXML-Layout)   -              activity_kids_game
(06) Class                      -              Common
(07) Custom Layout              -              item_main_image
(08) Adapter                    -              KidsGameAdapter
(09) Interface                  -              KidsGamesItemClick

To Get Sub Iamge From Same API (category_name)

Type                       -              Name

(10) Activity(Main)             -              KidsGameListActivity
(11) Activity(MainXML-Layout)   -              activity_kids_game_list
(12) Custom Layout              -              item_sub_image
(13) Adapter                    -              KidsGameListAdapter
(14) Interface                  -              KidsGamesListItemClick
```

---

(01) Model Class                -              Main Image Item

```
package com.example.childrenartsdrawing.models;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainImageItem {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("profile_image")
    @Expose
    private String profileImage;
    @SerializedName("category_name")
    @Expose
    private String categoryName;
    @SerializedName("category_images")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<SubImageItem> categoryImages = null;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProfileImage() {
        return profileImage;
    }

    public void setProfileImage(String profileImage) {
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public ArrayList<SubImageItem> getCategoryImages() {
        return categoryImages;
    }

    public void setCategoryImages(ArrayList<SubImageItem> categoryImages) {
        this.categoryImages = categoryImages;
    }
}
```

(02) Model Class                -              Sub Image Item

```
package com.example.childrenartsdrawing.models;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SubImageItem {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("image_url")
    @Expose
    private String imageUrl;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

(03) Interface(Api)             -              KidsGameApiCall

```
package com.example.childrenartsdrawing.interfaces;

import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.models.MainImageItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface KidsGamesApiCall {
    @GET("kidsgames.json")
    Call<ArrayList<MainImageItem>> getMainImageList();
}
```

(04) Activity(Main)             -              KidsGameActivity

```
package com.example.childrenartsdrawing.activities;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.adapter.KidsGameAdapter;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.common.Common;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.databinding.ActivityKidsGameBinding;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.interfaces.KidsGamesApiCall;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.interfaces.KidsGamesItemClick;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.models.MainImageItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class KidsGameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements KidsGamesItemClick {

    ActivityKidsGameBinding binding;
    ArrayList<MainImageItem> mainImageItems = new ArrayList<>();
    KidsGameAdapter adapter;
    Retrofit retrofit;
    KidsGamesApiCall services;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        binding = ActivityKidsGameBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        init();
        toolBarClick();
    }

    private void init() {
        binding.myToolbar.tvTitle.setText("Kids Game");
        binding.myToolbar.icActionSetting.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        callImageAPI();
    }

    private void toolBarClick() {
        binding.myToolbar.icActionBack.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            onBackPressed();
            Common.myButtonSound(this);
        });
    }

    private void callImageAPI() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://___________.in/childrenart/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        services = retrofit.create(KidsGamesApiCall.class);

        drawingData();
    }

    private void drawingData() {
        Call<ArrayList<MainImageItem>> call = services.getMainImageList();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<MainImageItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<MainImageItem>> call, @NonNull Response<ArrayList<MainImageItem>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    mainImageItems = response.body();
                    Common.mainListImage = mainImageItems; // save received list in Common
                    if (Common.mainListImage != null) {

                        initRecyclerView(); // Here we set adapter

                        binding.llProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<MainImageItem>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(KidsGameActivity.this, "Please Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    private void initRecyclerView() {
        adapter = new KidsGameAdapter(KidsGameActivity.this, mainImageItems, this);
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(KidsGameActivity.this, 2);
        binding.rvDrawingBookList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        binding.rvDrawingBookList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void passDrawingPosition(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, KidsGameListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("KIDS_GAME_POSITION", position);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnKidsGameItemClick(MainImageItem kidsGameItem, int position) {
        Common.myBtnCategorySound(this);
        passDrawingPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (Common.homeMusic != null)
            Common.homeMusic.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Common.homeMusic.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

(05) Activity(MainXML-Layout)   -              activity_kids_game
You Can make custom layout for custom_action_bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_drawing"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.DrawingBookActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/custom_action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/llDrawingBook"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.083"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/llProgress"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:layout_width="168dp"
            android:layout_height="217dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_imageAssetsFolder="images"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/progress_2"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvDrawingBookList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

(06) Class                      -              Common

```
package com.example.childrenartsdrawing.common;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.R;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.models.MainImageItem;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.models.MyGalleryItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Common {

    // Here we store MainImageItem in array list    
    public static ArrayList<MainImageItem> mainListImage;

    public static int musicHome, buttonSound, btnCancel,buttonDelete;
    public static MediaPlayer homeMusic, buttonClickSound,mpCancel, mpClickSound,mpBtnBig,mpBtnCategory,mpItemSound,deleteSound;
    public static Boolean soundOn = true;

    public static ArrayList<MyGalleryItem> MY_GALLERY_IMAGES;


    public static void myMusicStart(Context mContext) {
        musicHome = R.raw.music12bg;
        homeMusic = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, musicHome);
        homeMusic.start();
    }

    public static void myButtonSound(Context mContext) {
        if (Common.soundOn) {
            buttonSound = R.raw.sound_btn_play;
            buttonClickSound = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, buttonSound);
            buttonClickSound.start();
        }
    }

    public static void onClickSound(Context mContext) {
        if (Common.soundOn) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int[] myMusic = {R.raw.music_01, R.raw.music_02, R.raw.music_03, R.raw.music_04, R.raw.music_05, R.raw.music_06, R.raw.music_07, R.raw.music_08, R.raw.music_09, R.raw.music_10, R.raw.music_11};
            int i = random.nextInt(myMusic.length);
            mpClickSound = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, myMusic[i]);
            mpClickSound.start();
        }
    }
}
```

(07) Custom Layout              -              item_main_image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- 2 -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llCustomDrawAct"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMainItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

(08) Adapter                    -              KidsGameAdapter

```
package com.example.childrenartsdrawing.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.databinding.ItemMainImageBinding;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.interfaces.KidsGamesItemClick;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.models.MainImageItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class KidsGameAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<KidsGameAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    ItemMainImageBinding binding;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<MainImageItem> itemList;
    // i3 & create constructor also
    private KidsGamesItemClick setMainItemClick;

    public KidsGameAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MainImageItem> itemList, KidsGamesItemClick setMainItemClick) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.setMainItemClick = setMainItemClick;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        binding = ItemMainImageBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(binding);
        return holder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MainImageItem item = itemList.get(position);

//      holder.binding.tvMainItem.setText(item.getCategoryName());
        Glide.with(context).load(item.getProfileImage()).into(holder.binding.ivMainItem);
//        i4
        holder.binding.ivMainItem.setOnClickListener(view -> setMainItemClick.OnKidsGameItemClick(item,position));
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ItemMainImageBinding binding;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull ItemMainImageBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }
    }
}
```

(09) Interface                  -              KidsGamesItemClick

```
package com.example.childrenartsdrawing.interfaces;

import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.models.MainImageItem;

public interface KidsGamesItemClick {
    void OnKidsGameItemClick(MainImageItem kidsGameItem, int position);
}
```

(10) Activity(Main)             -              KidsGameListActivity

```
package com.example.childrenartsdrawing.activities;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.adapter.KidsGameListAdapter;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.common.Common;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.databinding.ActivityKidsGameListBinding;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.interfaces.KidsGamesListItemClick;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.models.SubImageItem;

public class KidsGameListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements KidsGamesListItemClick {

    ActivityKidsGameListBinding binding;
    int mMainListPos;
    KidsGameListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        binding = ActivityKidsGameListBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        mMainListPos = getIntent().getIntExtra("KIDS_GAME_POSITION", 0);

        init();
        toolBarClick();
        binding.myToolbar.icActionSetting.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void init() {
        initRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        adapter = new KidsGameListAdapter(this, Common.mainListImage.get(mMainListPos).getCategoryImages(), this);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        binding.rvSubList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        binding.rvSubList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (Common.homeMusic != null)
            Common.homeMusic.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (Common.homeMusic != null)
            Common.homeMusic.pause();
    }

    private void toolBarClick() {
        binding.myToolbar.icActionBack.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            onBackPressed();
            Common.myButtonSound(this);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void setKidsListSubItemClick(SubImageItem subImageItem, int position) {
        String subImageUrl = subImageItem.getImageUrl();
        String activityName = KidsGameListActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, PaintDrawActivity.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("ACTIVITY_NAME",activityName);
        bundle.putString("SUB_IMAGE_URL", subImageUrl);
        bundle.putInt("SUB_IMAGE_POSITION", position);
        bundle.putInt("MAIN_IMAGE_POSITION", mMainListPos);
        myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        Common.myBtnItemSound(this);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
}
```

(11) Activity(MainXML-Layout)   -              activity_kids_game_list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_drawing"
    tools:context=".activities.DrawingBookListActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llLoader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/custom_action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/llDrawingBook"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.083"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSubList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

(12) Custom Layout              -              item_sub_image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- 2 -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_click"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/ic_image_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSubItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

(13) Adapter                    -              KidsGameListAdapter

```
package com.example.childrenartsdrawing.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.databinding.ItemSubImageBinding;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.interfaces.KidsGamesListItemClick;
import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.models.SubImageItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class KidsGameListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<KidsGameListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ItemSubImageBinding binding;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SubImageItem> itemList;
    // i3 & create constructor also
    private KidsGamesListItemClick subItemClick;

    public KidsGameListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SubImageItem> itemList, KidsGamesListItemClick subItemClick) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.subItemClick = subItemClick;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public KidsGameListAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        binding = ItemSubImageBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),parent,false);
        KidsGameListAdapter.MyViewHolder holder = new KidsGameListAdapter.MyViewHolder(binding);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SubImageItem item = itemList.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(itemList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(holder.binding.ivSubItem);
        holder.binding.cardClick.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            subItemClick.setKidsListSubItemClick(item,position);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ItemSubImageBinding binding;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull ItemSubImageBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }
    }
}
```

(14) Interface                  -              KidsGamesListItemClick

```
package com.example.childrenartsdrawing.interfaces;

import com.example.childrenartsdrawing.models.SubImageItem;

public interface KidsGamesListItemClick {
    void setKidsListSubItemClick(SubImageItem subImageItem, int position);
}
```